# MongoEngine: Order by field of Model in ReferenceField

Tags: python, mongodb, reference, sql-order-by, mongoengine

I have a model (PublicationToPerson) with ReferenceFields referencing objects of another model (Publication). Now I’m trying to order a PublicationToPerson QuerySet by a field which is in the Publication object.

My current approach is `PublicationToPerson.objects.filter(person=curr_person).order_by(“publication__release_year”)`, but this seems to have no effect on the order. I suppose mongeengine doesn’t support this (you may prove me wrong, of course). Is there any way I can achieve this? Maybe with a raw request?

My Models:

```
class Publication(Document): 
    title = StringField(required=True, unique_with=['dblp_key']) internal_type = StringField(required=False) 
    dblp_key = StringField(required=True, unique=True)
     mdate = DateTimeField(required=False)
    […]
     release_year = IntField(required=False)


class PublicationToPerson(Document): 
    role = StringField(required=True, unique_with=['publication', 'person']) 
    publication = ReferenceField(document_type=Publication, required=True)
    person = ReferenceField(document_type=Person, required=True)
```

Answer (score -1):

Does someone have an answer for this?
I have been looking for this for a long time but did not find anything directly in mongoengine.
Best workaround I found is:

```
publications = PublicationToPerson.objects.filter(person=curr_person).select_related(1)
publications = sorted(publications, key=lambda r: (r.publication.release_year))
```

But it does not use Mongo internal sorting feature.